# NRefactory , move method

Tags: refactoring, monodevelop, sharpdevelop, nrefactory

I am trying to use NRefactory for my refactorings, 
I have an old style code written in non OOP style

the thing I need to do is for each class T move static methods accepting T as first parameter type into a new class ExtensionsForT and change references to it look like X.method1(t)=>t.method1()

```
//------------------original-------------------------------------------
class BigClass{
   //method is referenced here
   public BigClass(){
       Reader r=new Reader();
       //...
       Next(r);
   }

   //method to refactor
   public static bool Next( Reader r){
       //...
   }

}


//-------------------- want to achieve this-------------------------
class BigClass{
   //method is referenced here
   public BigClass(){
       Reader r=new Reader();
       //...
       r.Next();
   }

}

public class ReaderExtensions{
    //method to refactor
   public static bool Next(this Reader r){
       //...
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your question about programming? Please read the **help** pages linked from the top of each Stackoverflow page, there are sections on how to write a good question that will encourage good answers.

Comment: My question is about using NRefactory for refactoring my code.

refactoring I want to do is change method from static method to an extension method in another class.